# Problem with access to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've asked a similar question before but that was about events related to dynamically created elements. Now I just want to change class lists of dynamically created img tags in a div. Here is what is all about, I want to create a slider that contains three images taken with src and alt attributes taken from a JSON file. Function created all three normally and as I wanted put displayNone class on every img except first. Another function should on every 3 seconds check in a loop all the dynamically created img tags for the one that does not contain displayNone class and to add to that particular img class displayNone and then to get next, or if it is last first, img and to remove his displayNone class. I created var inside function to get an array of these images. Does anybody know what the solution is?

```
function showSlides(slidesJsonData){ // there is no problem with this function it generates img tags when window is loaded
    var writingSlides = "";
    for (slide in slidesJsonData){
        if(slide==0){
            writingSlides += `<img src="${slidesJsonData[slide].src}" alt="${slidesJsonData[slide].alt}"/>`;
        }
        writingSlides += `<img class="displayNone" src="${slidesJsonData[slide].src}" alt="${slidesJsonData[slide].alt}"/>`;
    }
    document.querySelector("#slider").innerHTML=writingSlides;
}
function slideShow(){
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("#slider img");
    images.forEach((img,index) => {
        if(index<images.length-1){
            if(!img.classList.contains("displayNone")){
                img.classList.add("displayNone");
                img[index+1].classList.remove("displayNone");
            }
        }
        else {
            img.classList.add("displayNone");
            document.querySelector("#slider img:first-of-type").classList.remove("displayNone");
        }
    });
    setTimeout("slideShow()",3000);
}
slideShow();
Now error is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at main.js:73
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at slideShow (main.js:69)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: If your first console.log gives an empty array, then it's a problem with how you're setting `sliderImages` variable and any code beyond that is irrelevant until that variable is working.

Comment: You need to call `var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll("#slider img");` AFTER you added the images

Comment: I almost guarantee you your first line of code is running before the elements are on the page

Comment: The fact that they're dynamically created has no bearing on this - just *when* (and maybe *how* if they're not in #slider) or if you have multiple #slider.  An [mcve] in a snippet would show this issue clear enough.

Comment: Don't use a `for in` loop on an element collection. It is not an array but an array-like object with numerous other properties that are not index related

Comment: @mplungjan, I did actually call that line after I added the images. I added images in one function and in next function is all the code I wrote above.

Comment: So the solution is `[...document.querySelectorAll("#slider img")].forEach(img => if (img.classList......)`

Comment: You cannot use index + 1 if it does not exist so test first!`if (index < images.length-1) ...

Comment: @mplungjan Now I modified the code to looks for length of array but again there is an error regarding to classList.

Comment: Now error is relating to this line img[index+1].classList.remove("displayNone");

Answer (score 0):

try updating your sliderImages variable before accessing it because it probably is being created before content as finished loading

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `for in` loop that exposes other enumerable properties of the element collection unrelated to element indexing. Element collections are not proper arrays but rather are *array-like* objects

When you try to pass these properties to `sliderImages[sliderImage]` inside your loop they do not return an element with a  `classList` property and no sub property `contains` which throws the error.

Use a for loop based on `length` or a `for of` loop or `sliderImages.forEach(callback)`

---

Simple property  output example of the `for in`

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li')

for (let x in li) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    console.log(`Property "${x}" is not an element index`)
  } else {
    console.log(`Key "${x}" is an element index`)
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("#slider img");
let cnt= 0
function slideShow(){
  images[cnt].classList.toggle("displayNone")
  cnt++
  if (cnt>= images.length) cnt = 0;
  images[cnt].classList.toggle("displayNone")
}
setInterval(slideShow,3000);
```