# How do I hide a table row if there is a null value or a specific value

Tags: javascript, css, row, hide

I'm not much of a javascript coder, but I'm trying to write something to make my work a little easier...

I have a table of data.  The third cell of the table ('offersTable') is a display flag, which will either be 'Y', 'N', or empty.  The source for the table is incomplete, which is why sometimes the cell is empty (null).

I'm trying to write a small script that will iterate down through the table, and then set the row to hide if the value if the cell is either 'N' or null.  That way, only rows which have a 'Y' remain.

Please can someone help me?  I'm going out of my mind trying to work this one out!

Sorry, I should have included my code...

```
<table id="offersTable">
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Lender</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Lender Code</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Display</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Loan Offered</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Term Offered</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Approval Probability</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(6)">APR</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Monthly Repayment</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(8)">Total Repayable</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lender1">
            <td id="lender1Name"><script>document.getElementById("lender1Name").innerHTML = offers[0].lender_name;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1Code"><script>document.getElementById("lender1Code").innerHTML = offers[0].lender_code;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1Display"><script>document.getElementById("lender1Display").innerHTML = offers[0].display;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1Value"><script>document.getElementById("lender1Value").innerHTML = offers[0].loan_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1Term"><script>document.getElementById("lender1Term").innerHTML = offers[0].term_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1AppProb"><script>document.getElementById("lender1AppProb").innerHTML = offers[0].approval_probability;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1APR"><script>document.getElementById("lender1APR").innerHTML = offers[0].apr;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1MonthlyRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender1MonthlyRepay").innerHTML = offers[0].monthly_repayment;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender1TotalRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender1TotalRepay").innerHTML = offers[0].total_repayment;</script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lender2">
            <td id="lender2Name"><script>document.getElementById("lender2Name").innerHTML = offers[1].lender_name;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2Code"><script>document.getElementById("lender2Code").innerHTML = offers[1].lender_code;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2Display"><script>document.getElementById("lender2Display").innerHTML = offers[1].display;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lende2Value"><script>document.getElementById("lender2Value").innerHTML = offers[1].loan_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2Term"><script>document.getElementById("lender2Term").innerHTML = offers[1].term_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2AppProb"><script>document.getElementById("lender2AppProb").innerHTML = offers[1].approval_probability;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2APR"><script>document.getElementById("lender2APR").innerHTML = offers[1].apr;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2MonthlyRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender2MonthlyRepay").innerHTML = offers[1].monthly_repayment;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender2TotalRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender2TotalRepay").innerHTML = offers[1].total_repayment;</script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lender3">
            <td id="lender3Name"><script>document.getElementById("lender3Name").innerHTML = offers[2].lender_name;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3Code"><script>document.getElementById("lender3Code").innerHTML = offers[2].lender_code;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3Display"><script>document.getElementById("lender3Display").innerHTML = offers[2].display;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3Value"><script>document.getElementById("lender3Value").innerHTML = offers[2].loan_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3Term"><script>document.getElementById("lender3Term").innerHTML = offers[2].term_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3AppProb"><script>document.getElementById("lender3AppProb").innerHTML = offers[2].approval_probability;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3APR"><script>document.getElementById("lender3APR").innerHTML = offers[2].apr;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3MonthlyRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender3MonthlyRepay").innerHTML = offers[2].monthly_repayment;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender3TotalRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender3TotalRepay").innerHTML = offers[2].total_repayment;</script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="lender4">
            <td id="lender4Name"><script>document.getElementById("lender4Name").innerHTML = offers[3].lender_name;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4Code"><script>document.getElementById("lender4Code").innerHTML = offers[3].lender_code;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4Display"><script>document.getElementById("lender4Display").innerHTML = offers[3].display;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4Value"><script>document.getElementById("lender4Value").innerHTML = offers[3].loan_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4Term"><script>document.getElementById("lender4Term").innerHTML = offers[3].term_offered;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4AppProb"><script>document.getElementById("lender4AppProb").innerHTML = offers[3].approval_probability;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4APR"><script>document.getElementById("lender4APR").innerHTML = offers[3].apr;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4MonthlyRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender4MonthlyRepay").innerHTML = offers[3].monthly_repayment;</script>
            </td>
            <td id="lender4TotalRepay"><script>document.getElementById("lender4TotalRepay").innerHTML = offers[3].total_repayment;</script>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should try doing it yourself first. If you get stuck post your issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Header A</td> 
    <td>Header B</td>
    <td>Filtered to</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 1</td> 
    <td>Info B 1</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 2</td> 
    <td>Info B 2</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 3</td> 
    <td>Info B 3</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 4</td> 
    <td>Info B 4</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 5</td> 
    <td>Info B 5</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Header A</td> 
    <td>Header B</td>
    <td>Filtered to</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 1</td> 
    <td>Info B 1</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 2</td> 
    <td>Info B 2</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 3</td> 
    <td>Info B 3</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 4</td> 
    <td>Info B 4</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 5</td> 
    <td>Info B 5</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function filterTable(table, cellIndex, filter) {
    for (var i = 1, tr; tr = table.rows[i]; i++) { // skip first line
        var third_td = tr.cells[cellIndex];
        tr.style.display = third_td.innerText === filter ? '' : 'none';
    }
}

function filterAllTables(cellIndex, filter) {
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
  if  (tables.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0, table; table = tables[i]; i++) {
      filterTable(table, cellIndex, filter);
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  filterAllTables(2, 'Y');
});
</script>
```

Comment: René - many thanks for your response - your solution works very well, I appreciate your help with this.  Is there a way that I can apply your code, but not apply the rule to the header row?  Also, I'd like to make it table-specific, as there may be scope for me to put a second table below it.  many thanks.

Comment: i did it, but to make it table specific, the solution have to be table specific aswell. That you have to code yourself, better tell me what you don't understand, that makes it easier to help.

Comment: I have amended the code to start at row 1 (so that the header remains).  You solution works perfectly now.  I will try and work out how to make it table-specific.  René, many thanks for your help once more.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe try css: display: hidden; Also check out this website or research some before posting. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122023/hide-html-table-rows-if-outputfield-is-null-or-0 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code is difficult but i know this solution with js:

```
for (i in document.querySelectorAll('td')) {
        if (document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].textContent == 'N' || document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].textContent == 'null' ) {
            document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].remove()
        }
    }
```

i'm using "remove" only to demonstrate it but you can use style.property...

Comment: Don't use `for in` for an element collection. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210052/1175966

Answer (score 0):

I went with this option as it worked perfectly, operating in exactly the way that I wanted.  Many thanks to René Datenschutz for the solution.

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Header A</td> 
    <td>Header B</td>
    <td>Filtered to</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 1</td> 
    <td>Info B 1</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 2</td> 
    <td>Info B 2</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 3</td> 
    <td>Info B 3</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 4</td> 
    <td>Info B 4</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 5</td> 
    <td>Info B 5</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Header A</td> 
    <td>Header B</td>
    <td>Filtered to</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 1</td> 
    <td>Info B 1</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 2</td> 
    <td>Info B 2</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 3</td> 
    <td>Info B 3</td>
    <td>Y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 4</td> 
    <td>Info B 4</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Info A 5</td> 
    <td>Info B 5</td>
    <td>N</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function filterTable(table, cellIndex, filter) {
    for (var i = 1, tr; tr = table.rows[i]; i++) { // skip first line
        var third_td = tr.cells[cellIndex];
        tr.style.display = third_td.innerText === filter ? '' : 'none';
    }
}

function filterAllTables(cellIndex, filter) {
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
  if  (tables.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0, table; table = tables[i]; i++) {
      filterTable(table, cellIndex, filter);
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  filterAllTables(2, 'Y');
});
</script>
```